# Create nested element using DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create something like this using only DOM:

```
<div class="parent">
     <p><div id="child1">My First Child</div></p>
     <div id="child2"><p>Second Child Node</p></div>
</div>
```

And I have only manage to create each individual element like so:

```
  let div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div1.setAttribute("class", "parent");
  let div2 = document.createElement("div");
  div2.setAttribute("id", "child1");  
  div2.textContent = "My First Child";
  let div3 = document.createElement("div");
  div3.setAttribute("id", "child2");
  div3.textContent = "Second Child Node";
```

My question here is: Can I combine everything into one so I only have to use `document.appendChild(div1)` or does the nesting process needs to be done during the append process.

Comment: `div1.appendChild(div2), div1.appendChild(div3), document.body.appendChild(div1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` contain single child i.e `div` with class `parent` stored in `parentDiv`.

`parentDiv` contain 2 child i.e `p` and `div` with id `child2`

`p` container single child i.e `div` with id `child1`

`div` with id `child2` contain single `p`

---

`body` = (`p`) + (`div`) where

`p` contains `div` with id `child1`

`div` with id `child2` contains `p`

```js
const parentDiv = document.createElement("div")
parentDiv.classList.add("parent");

const p1 = document.createElement("p");
const divChild1 = document.createElement("div");
divChild1.setAttribute("id", "child1");
divChild1.textContent = "My First Child";
p1.appendChild(divChild1);

const divChild2 = document.createElement("div");
divChild2.setAttribute("id", "child2");
const p2 = document.createElement("p");
p2.textContent = "Second Child Node";
divChild2.appendChild(p2);

parentDiv.appendChild(p1);
parentDiv.appendChild(divChild2);

document.body.appendChild(parentDiv)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
document
  .querySelector(".parent-of-parent")
  .insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
    <div class="parent">
      <p><div id="child1">My First Child</div></p>
      <div id="child2"><p>Second Child Node</p></div>
    </div>`
  );
```

```html
<div class="parent-of-parent"></div>
```